# How do I overlap components inside a ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to overlap components inside a constraint layout. I would like to have the bottom of `Team One` to be on top of the `vs` container. I was able to align it by using the `app:layout_constraintVertical_bias` attribute. When the keyboard expands, the component is not responsive. It will push the `Team One` over the `vs` past the point of being flush with top of the `vs` container.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/team_divider_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/team_one_name_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxWidth="200dp"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/team_two_name"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias=".3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/select_teams_container">


        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center|end"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_gravity="center|start"
                android:id="@+id/team_one_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:focusedByDefault="false"
                android:cursorVisible="true"
                android:minWidth="100dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/color_picker_circle"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                android:text="@string/start_game"
                android:inputType="textCapCharacters|textNoSuggestions"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MyTheme.Headline1"/>

            <com.madrapps.pikolo.HSLColorPicker
                android:id="@+id/team_one_color_picker"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias=".75"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/team_one_name"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                android:id="@+id/color_picker_circle"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                app:cardElevation="2dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/color_primary"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/team_one_name"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/team_one_color_picker"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/team_one_name"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/team_one_name"
                app:shapeAppearance="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.MaterialCardView.Circle"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/confirm_team_one_color_btn"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_check_circle_black_48dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/team_one_color_picker"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias=".25"/>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/team_two_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="100dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:cursorVisible="true"
        android:focusedByDefault="false"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:inputType="textCapCharacters|textNoSuggestions"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MyTheme.Headline1"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/select_teams_container"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/select_teams_container"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".25" />


    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/select_teams_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:strokeWidth="2dp"
        app:strokeColor="@color/color_primary"
        app:shapeAppearance="@style/ShapeAppearance.MaterialComponents.MediumComponent.TeamSelectCard"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".6"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".55">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/team_one_container"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/team_two_container"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/team_one_recyclerView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:overScrollMode="never"
                    android:weightSum="5"
                    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    tools:itemCount="5"
                    tools:listitem="@layout/playercard_draggable" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/vertical_divider"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="VS"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.MyTheme.Headline1"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/team_one_container"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/team_two_container"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/team_two_container"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/team_one_container"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/team_two_recyclerView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:weightSum="5"
                    android:overScrollMode="never"
                    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    tools:itemCount="5"
                    tools:listitem="@layout/playercard_draggable" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

When I don't use vertical bias:

[image]

When I use vertical bias:
[image]

When the keyboard is expanded:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I cant do simple comments on the initial post yet.

But it look as if your `team_one_color_picker` view has a set height of 200, which is making the parent view not fit in the available screen correctly. Try changing that height param to be something dynamic

Also your `team_one_name_container` object can be a height of 0dp since it is constrained at the top and bottom.

Answer (score 0):

First, set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNotjing"` in the manifest file or through the Java code, so that your view does not change when the keyboard is in open or closed state, and then you can use `translationY=-10dp` or any particular dp depending on your need for `Team1` to move it on to the top of `vs` container.